# How do I return JSON and loop through the returned json in jQuery in MVC app?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC controller that returns JSON.
I want to read/get that JSON using jQuery and loop through the json items/rows.

Basically I am reading bunch of comments and then show the comments one by one.

Does anyone have code sample to do it?

I get the json correctly. See returned data below.

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/comment/GetComments",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "blog_id=100&page_size=5&page_no=1",
        success: function (result) {
            //loop the data.. how do I loop json?
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert('Error getting comments');
        }
    });

    My controller:

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetComments(string blog_id, int page_size, int page_no)
    {            
        try
        {                
            List<Comment> comments = ReadCommentsFromDB();

            if(comments .Count > 0)                
                return Json(new { comments = cmts.ToJson() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new { comments = "none" },, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { comments = ex.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

How do I loop these json returned by controller?
I need to loop 3 times and then for each row, I need to have access to all keys and values
in that row.

```
[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "First comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966277978 } }, 
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "Second comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966347677 } }, 
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "Third comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966493240 } }
]
```

Comment: you did remove [HttpPost] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first problem is to allow Json to work in a GET.  Json normally only work for a post.  You allow Json in GET by using the following return method in your controller (using one of your return statements).

```
return Json(new { comments = "none" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

**Edit:** You can also return `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` as seen below.

```
public ActionResult GetComments(string blog_id, int page_size, int page_no)    
{           
    try        
    {
        List<Comment> comments = ReadCommentsFromDB();

        // Assuming that Comments will be an empty list if there are no data
        return Json(comments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { comments = ex.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepting this. I will ask another question about the looping part.

Answer (score 4):

```
success: function(result) {
    $.each(result["comments"], function(key, value) {
        // loop
    });
}
```

Your result should be a json object

```
{
    "comments": ...
}
```

As for the get failing try :

```
type: "GET",
url: "/comment/GetComments?blog_id=100&page_size=5&page_no=1",
dataType: "json",
//data: "blog_id=100&page_size=5&page_no=1",
```

Comment: $.each(result["comments"], function(key, value) {} seems an infinite loop. Look at my sample data. Are you sure it will loop the result just 3 times? It keep looping.

Comment: @Projapati it's not an infinite loop.

Comment: This is my callback. It keep alerting.    success: function (result) {                
                $.each(result["comments"], function (key, value) {
                    alert('comment found');
                });
            }

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/comment/GetComments",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "blog_id=100&page_size=5&page_no=1",
        success: function (result) {
            jQuery.each(result['comments'], function(key,val){
               // do stuff :)
            });
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert('Error getting comments');
        }
    });
```

Comment: or rather, `$.each(result['comments'],function(i,e){ /* e is now an element in the JSON object */ });`. Also, not positive, but don't you need to reference `result.d`?

Comment: @Atticus yes I realised it was far too harsh and removed it.

Comment: jQuery.each(result['comments'], function(key,val){
               // do stuff :)
            }); might an infinite loop. It is supposed to loop just 3 time as I have 3 top level json objects. Am I missing something?

Comment: The loop is infinite. Even if I just return 1 comment, loop never ends!!

Comment: How should I know when to stop? I gave 3 as an example. It can be any. $.each() is supposed to loop whatever I have...

Answer (score 1):

Remove [HttpPost] from your controller method to allow get requests in conjunction with JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

What internal server error do you get? what is the message?

Comment: Thanks Adam. First problem is solved. But your answer is correct.