# How do I loop JSON data returned by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I return JSON and loop through the returned json in jQuery in MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953761/how-do-i-return-json-and-loop-through-the-returned-json-in-jquery-in-mvc-app)

This is my data returned by MVC controller and I get this in my success callback:

```
[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "First comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966277978 } }, 
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "Second comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966347677 } }, 
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4dc8" }, "eid" : { "$oid" : "4da" }, "user" : "bob", "text" : "Third comment!!", "dt" : { "$date" : 1304966493240 } }
]
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetComments(params...)
{
   return Json(new { comments = GetFromDB().ToJson() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Problem:**
I tried several ways to loop the rows. But all seems infinite loop.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/comment/GetComments",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "app=" + app + "&eid=" + eid + "&pg=" + pg + "&pgs=" + pgs,
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result[comments], function () {
                   $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        alert('this a column or attribute');
                   });
                   alert('end of row');
               });
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert('Error=' + error + ' & Status=' + status);
            }
        });
```

Also tried:

```
$.each(result["comments"], function (key, value) {
   alert('comment found');
});
```

How can I loop the rows & access each attribute's value?

Comment: what does your ajax call look like?

Comment: please edit your post rather than pasting code in commment

Comment: you posted basically the same thing today at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953761/how-do-i-return-json-and-loop-through-the-returned-json-in-jquery-in-mvc-app/5954010#5954010

Comment: Adam, That is right. I commented there that I will post another just for my second problem. I was not getting answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
    // do something with results[i].text
}
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/MB5j3/)

---

EDIT: If you need to first convert a JSON string to a Javascript object then before the loop you should:

```
results = JSON.parse(results);
```

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle but not on my browser. alert('len=' + results.length) prints me the total characters in the json response not the number of items in the response. Is that the reason? It is treating json as plain text??

Comment: JSON is a text format: http://www.json.org/

Comment: After adding results = JSON.parse(results), it seems working & i can traverse it. Why do I need this? I have specified dataType: "json" in my GET call and my controller also returns JsonResult. Just not getting it..

Comment: JSON is a method of transferring Javascript objects as a string, but it is NOT a Javascript object.  See comment from @Tamler and read up on that link

Comment: OK. Valid json but js can't process it unless I convert it to js object first. But didn't see others doing this same way.

Comment: +1 for initializing `len` instead of inspecting `length` in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("YourControllerHere.XXX",{}, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#someLocation').append('<li>' + val.text + '</li>'); //This is just an example. You can do something with each row/ value pair here.
    });
});
```

You should be able to step through the rows and values with this.

Best,

T

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate from another post today - that you posted?  : )

[How do I return JSON and loop through the returned json in jQuery in MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953761/how-do-i-return-json-and-loop-through-the-returned-json-in-jquery-in-mvc-app/5954010#5954010)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that there is no `result["comments"]` field in your JSON.  You're getting an array back, of what I assume is the comments themselves.  So you need to iterate on that.  Something like

```
$.each(result, function(k, v) { console.log(v.user); });
```

should work, I just tried it in the browser. The following code iterates through the rows, and then iterates through the attributes of each row:

```
$.each(foo, function(k, row) { $.each(row, function(attr, value) { console.log(attr, value); }) });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var key in json)
    for(var key in (obj = json[key]))
        {
            //obj holds the current object in the json array
            console.log(obj[key]);   
        }
```