# jquery and mvc .net : action return json returns "object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

So I have a json that calls a JsonResult

The class:

```
public class Client{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The action being called:

```
public JsonResult Index(int Id)
        {
      var a = context.Clients.ToList();
      return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this is the call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var link;
        $('a.client-list').click(function () {
            link= $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/client/index?Id=4455',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (id, val) {
                        alert(id.toString() + ' ' + val.toString());
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

So my problem is, I know that it returns something cuz it loops through the alert that I put in. but the value that pops out is this

```
0 [object Object]
1 [object Object]
```

I'm not sure why it's not reading it properly. The values queried btw are

```
1 TestCompany1
2 TestCompany2
```

Am I missing something on the jquery??

Comment: Are you sure that the `TestCompany1` and `TestCompany2` values you're getting back are strings? If they're any other kind of object (except for ones that can be converted to strings), your `.toString()` isn't gonna know how to convert it to a string.

Comment: Wouldn't each `val` be a `Client` object? So maybe it would be `val.Name`?

Comment: well, the Id is an int, and the Name is of string property. I thought I can just pass an IEnumerable or a var to the json and the getjson will take care of it? no? @MrOBrian I also tried that and still the same..

Comment: you may need to analyse the structure of the returned json. Also, I'm not sure if it's causing confusion, but the `id` in `$.each(data, function (id, val)` is not `Client.Id`, but rather the array index. It may be easier (and less overhead) to use a standard javascript for loop there instead of `$.each`

Comment: something like this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954633/how-do-i-loop-json-data-returned-by-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your $.each like so:

```
$.each( data, function (index, client ) {
    alert( client.Id + ' ' + client.Name );
});
```

You are returning a collection (`Array`) of the Client type. The `$.each` function will provide the index of the array and the item in the array associated with the index. In this case, each item in the array will be a Client `Object`. More information on `$.each` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Fore more details when debugging JavaScript, try using the console:

```
$.each(data, function ( index, client ) {
    console.log( client );
});
```

Just hit F12 in your browser (PC) and select the console tab. You will be able to see more detail about the `Object` including its properties.